# How to create route that generates JS in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'd like to generate JavaScript code, and not just HTML, through Jinja2, am I stuck with keeping the JS code inline, or is there a way for me to reference the script? (to render js file in render_template())

My app tree:

```
|-----------static/  <--'static' folder
|                                                                    
|-----------static/assets/ <--'assets' folder
|                                                 
|-----------static/assets/js/   <-- customer.js and others here                                                     
|                        /js/custom script.js 
|-----------templates/ <-- html files                         
|-----------main.py  <-- Flask app here
```

Flask app:

```py
@app.route('/custom-scripts.js')
def script():
    res = [{key_list[0]: kerulet[idx], key_list[1]: eladasi_ar[idx]}
           for idx in range(0, n, 2)]
    data = str(res)
    return render_template('custom-scripts.js', data=data)
```

And in custom-script.js where I want to update/replace the "data" variable, this is in the /js  folder as other js files:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: {{ data }} 
});
```

layout.html:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

How could I pass the "data" variable to reflect in custom-script.js that is loaded in the layout.html file?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least two options:

1. Build JS file on the fly by Flask

```py
# main.py
...

@app.route('/')
def layout():
    ...
    return render_template('layout.html')


@app.route('/custom-scripts.js')
def script():
    ...
    return render_template('custom-scripts.js.jinja2', data=data)
```

But `custom-scripts.js.jinja2` should be in the `templates` folder:

```
// templates/custom-scripts.js.jinja2

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-chart',
    data: {{ data|tojson }}
});
```

```
<!-- templates/layout.html -->

<script src="{{ url_for('script') }}"></script>
```

2. Use `custom-scripts.js` as an ordinary static file and pass data to `layout.html` which initializes `custom-scripts.js` inside:

```
// static/assets/js/custom-script.js

function initMorrisBarChart(data) {
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'morris-bar-chart',
        data: data
    });
}
```

```
<!-- templates/layout.html -->

<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/custom-scripts.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    initMorrisBarChart({{ data|tojson }});
</script>
```

```py
# main.py
...

@app.route('/')
def layout():
    ...
    return render_template('layout.html', data=data)
```

`{{ data|tojson }}` is used to pass data (list of dicts) as JSON string to JavaScript function.

Comment: at first option: should the JSON file be renamed to "*.js.jinja2 when pulling in the template dir? I assume that in the layout.html file the reference link should placed like this: <script src="{{ url_for('custom-scripts.js') }}"></script> The reason I ask that this option does not seem to work. Or maybe anything with the import? I use jinja2 in the import

Comment: No, it should be: <script src="{{ url_for('script') }}"></script>. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I've added ".jinja2" just to emphasise that it's not JS file but a template. It's not mandatory for Flask, you can use any file extension.

Comment: Ok - the 2nd option looks better - the rest of the charts whiches are in the same script file are loading with their default data, but the chart where I want the data- does not come

Comment: At the second alternative, I'm getting this error: TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable. I have a feeling that I have two layout for the layout/ route and this could be the problem